# How to assign a weak reference outside of the header file?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
self.locationSearchBar.delegate = self;
```

I believe I have a retain cycle occurring here, and I can't for the life of me remember how to give the delegate a weak reference to self. Can someone tell me how to get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `locationSearchBar` is an instance of `UISearchBar`, `delegate` will already be an `assign`ed property declared as

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) id<UISearchBarDelegate> delegate
```

And if so, your code snippet is fine.

Otherwise, make sure `delegate` is declared as

```
@property (weak) id <YourProtocol> delegate
```

within the class's header.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not understanding how the instance of `locationSearchBar` will know that the class will be its delegate. could you explain?

Comment: Is `locationSearchBar` a `UISearchBar` or custom class you created?

Comment: Checkout the docs for UISearch bar here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBar_Class/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISearchBar/delegate

Comment: You'll see that `delegate` is declared as `@property(nonatomic, assign) id<UISearchBarDelegate> delegate`, so it does not retain whatever is assigned to it. So, you don't have a retain cycle. :)

Comment: in your post's last line, when you say "class's header", are you referring to class of my intended delegate (a view controller)?

Comment: Ah, I'm understanding now. It was a question of whether it was a custom class or UISearchBar. I get it. If this isn't a retain cycle then it seems I have nothing to worry about. Thank you!

Comment: Yep. This looks fine. If this solved the issue, please accept the answer. :D